# pivot_table - TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I'm looking to use the `pivot_table` function to display data instead of group by.

My Data:

```
df_Sample = df[['trading_book','state', 'rfq_num_of_dealers']].head(20)
df_Sample.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 20 entries, 0 to 19
Data columns (total 3 columns):
trading_book          20 non-null object
state                 20 non-null object
rfq_num_of_dealers    20 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 560.0+ bytes

df_Sample 

trading_book    state       rfq_num_of_dealers
SFICSUPR        Traded Away     6
SFICGOVT        Covered         6
SFICGOVT        Done            6
SFICGOVT        Dealer Timeout  5
SFICGOVT        Dealer Timeout  5
SFICGOVT        Dealer Timeout  5
SFICSUPR        Traded Away     5
SFICSUPR        Dealer Reject   2
SFICGOVT        Traded Away     5
SFICGOVT        Traded Away     5
SFICGOVT        Done            5
SFICGOVT        Customer Reject 3
SFICGOVT        Done            7
SFICSUPR        Dealer Reject   4
SFICSUPR        Dealer Reject   2
SFICSUPR        Dealer Reject   5
SFICSUPR        Dealer Reject   2
SFICSUPR        Dealer Reject   2
SFICSUPR        Traded Away     5
SFICSUPR        Dealer Reject   2
```

I converted the `rfq_num_of_dealers` column from `float64` to `str` and tried  object as well using this:

```
df_Sample['rfq_num_of_dealers'] = df[['rfq_num_of_dealers']].apply(str)
df_Sample['trading_book'] = df[['trading_book']].apply(str)
df_Sample['state'] = df[['state']].apply(str)
```

But the error persists:

```
pd.pivot_table(df_Sample, 
                index=['trading_book'],
                columns=['state'], 
                values='rfq_num_of_dealers',
                aggfunc='count')
```

> Error  TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and
>   'int'

Update 24/01/2018:

I dug a little deeper on this error. I did use the wrong dataframe but the error persisted when I increased the sample size. The set above is 20 rows , the original being 17 839 rows. I get the error when running the pivot_table on the large data set. If I limit the records read in to be 17839 no error is raised,

```
df_Sample = df[['trading_book','state', 'rfq_num_of_dealers']].head(17840)
```

Import one less record and no error is raised

```
df_Sample = df[['trading_book','state', 'rfq_num_of_dealers']].head(17839)
```

The EOF has a blank line followed by text: "(17839 row(s) affected)" as shown in the attached screenshot.

[Screenshot of EOF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLlba.png)

So what the best way to approach this? Limit the number of records imported or change the pivot_table command to ignore the EOF?

Comment: Your code is running fine for me. are you sure your getting the error from pd.pivot_table?

Comment: Found the issue. I was parsing the wring dataframe. Cheers

Comment: The issue persists. I updated the problem above.

Comment: Same thing happened to me with a large dataset. Anyone has a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a simple bug in my pivot column (the column that is used as pivot) 'STAGE' . In another file I had it setup as:

```
data.loc[data.URI.str.contains('X'), 'STAGE'] = '1'
data.loc[data.URI.str.contains('Y'), 'STAGE'] = '2'
data.loc[data.URI.str.contains('X'), 'STAGE'] = '3'
data.fillna({'STAGE':0}, inplace=True)
```

Notice how the default value is a float 0.0...